# How to implement a NSTabView delegate with MacRuby?

Tags: macruby

I try to set an NSTabView delegate using MacRuby with XCode, but I can't figure how to write the delegate. I use:

```
def intialize
@tab_changed.delegate = self
end

def tabViewdidSelectTabViewItem(a_notification)
puts "tab has changed"
end
```

Then in the .xib, I hook the NSTab view element with the class, but nothing happen when I select some tabs.
Usually the delegate are very easy to use, but this one has a syntax like this :
tabView:didSelectTabViewItem:

and I don't know how to write this in MacRuby. Should I use tabViewdidSelectTabViewItem or tabView_didSelectTabViewItem (none of them works).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is being done in a ViewController, instead of using `initialize`, better to do things the Cocoa way and use a method like `viewDidLoad`.

```
def viewDidLoad
   @tab_changed.delegate = self
end
```

The signature for the delegate method you want is `-(void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView didSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem`. In MacRuby, that would be represented like this:

```
def tabView(tabView, didSelectTabViewItem: tabViewItem)
   puts "tab has changed"
end
```